# How do I use an older Keycloak client with Quarkus 2.13, Keycloak 19 client is not backwards compatible with v18 server

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, quarkus

Would like to ask how to override the Keycloak version used by the Quarkus 2.13 BOM to Keycloak 18? My quarkus service could not connect to our Keycloak servers which still use v18. I have lost the error message in my logs but it said something about client secret is invalid when using Keycloak v19 client, but when downgrading to v18, there were no issues.

This PR [27387](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/27387) in Quarkus bumped the Keycloak version and it broke compatibility. I have tried overriding the property `<keycloak.version>18.0.2</keycloak.version>` in POM but it doesn't work, it keeps using the same dependency `org.keycloak:keycloak-core:19.0.2` and I even tried overriding the dependency `quarkus-keycloak-authorization` like so

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3.Final</version>  <!-- last quarkus version that used keycloak 18 -->
</dependency>
```

but it's still the same thing? I'm using a managed Keycloak server - Cloud IAM (Free tier) so any server upgrades wouldn't be easy. Or are there any alternative configurations I can use with Keycloak to make the client backward compatible, the error I'm encountering is the following during application startup

```java
2022-10-18 06:50:14,785 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile prod): 
org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 
401 / Unauthorized / Response from server: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Invalid client secret"}
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:95)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by overriding quarkus bom in `pom.xml` through `<dependencyManagement/>` like so, the keycloak pom should be above quarkus for it to override

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <!-- retain compatibility with keycloak 18 -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
        <!-- last quarkus version that used keycloak 18 -->
        <version>2.12.3.Final</version> 
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
  <dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I get a warning during mvn `compile` though, but as per this Issue [#1577](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1577), it is intended

```java
[io.quarkus.maven.MavenDevModeLauncher$Builder] io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-maven-
resolver::jar classpath entry C:\Users\Vince\.m2\repository\io\quarkus\quarkus-
bootstrap-maven-resolver\2.13.2.Final\quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver-2.13.2.
Final.jar was overriden with C:\Users\Vince\.m2\repository\io\quarkus\
quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver\2.12.3.Final\quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver-
2.12.3.Final.jar
```

Hope it can help others that were encountering the same issue, and take a quick read on the PR above, overriding the BOM versions can cause nasty unintended side effects.

Comment: Nice, that you share your answer, could you maker it as accepted